# (Matlab) Solving equation with different input

Tags: matlab

I have a task of creating a matlab program, and I was searching for "switch" and "if" functions for the task.

And the user will define any two of the variables, then matlab will solve for the other one. Normally, I would use "if" to account for different scenarios, but the increasing number of variables in the equation would increase the number of lines as well.

Updated with a demonstration:

```
% Mach Number after Shockwaves
M2=sqrt((((gamma-1).*M1.^2)+2)./(2*gamma.*M1.^2-(gamma-1)));

% Temperature Ratio
TR=((2*gamma.*M1.^2-(gamma-1)).*(((gamma-1).*M1.^2)+2))./(((gamma+1)^2).*M1.^2);

% Pressure Ratio
PR=(2*gamma.*M1.^2-(gamma-1))./(gamma+1);

% Density Ratio
rhoR=((gamma+1).*M1.^2)./(((gamma-1).*M1.^2)+2);

%Stagnant Pressure Ratio Before Shockwaves
P0R=(((1+0.2.*M2.^2)./(1+0.2.*M1.^2)).^(1.4/0.1)).*((2*gamma.*M1.^2-(gamma-1))./(gamma+1));

%Stagnant Pressure Ratio After Shockwaves
P1R=((1+0.2.*M2.^2).^(1.4/0.4)).*((2*gamma.*M1.^2-(gamma-1))./(gamma+1));
```

Is there any alternative? Also, the matlab running in my campus has no symbolic toolbox, so it would best to avoid it. I am at my wit's end now, for I am sure there is a simple solution to account for such scenario.

Further Updated with the exact equation:
The program will be able to do like, let's say the user enter "TR" and "gamma", and then Matlab will find the "M1". This would further be carried into subsequent equations, where I would get "M2","PR","rhoR","P0R" and "P1R". Also, I realised that since Matlab will read from top to bottom, is there any way to account for this?

Comment: It would help if you add your code

Comment: do you only need to support linear equations? then have a look at http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html

Comment: Added a simple code to demonstrate my problem.
@m.s. But could "linsolve" allows matlab to solve for the variable automatically, given the inputs from users?

Comment: is the example equation the only one you need to cover? if yes, then the calculation does not depend on whether `x` and `y`, or  `x` and `z`, or  `y` and `z` are given: `result = -a-b`; you should give more contextual information where you need this etc.

Comment: Do you need to call them X, Y, Z? Or can it be canged?

Comment: @BtcSources, they can be changed, they are just an arbitrary example.

Comment: @m.s. To further illustrate, this problem is on gas dynamics. Usually it will be that I define "gamma" and "temperature ratio", and then the output will be the mach number. However, I would like to make it universal, where user can choose to input, let's say mach number and temperature ratio, then the output will be mach number. I was hoping to create a "universal" equation, and let Matlab to automatically solve for the only variable in the equation once I run it.

Comment: how do you want to specify which of the inputs are supplied? if there are just 3 variables, I would not bother with such an approach, since the formulas are simple enough ...

Comment: @m.s. Perhaps I oversimplified the approach, sorry for that.  The actual program will contain about 8 equations, though, "gamma" and "Mach number" remains as the variables, followed by 8 others properties. That's why I was trying to approach it in least code possible, where I enter 8 equations into Matlab, and it will choose the output variables autonomously.

Comment: @Jethro: you might want to update your question with the real equations as well as the variables as well as how you would want to use such a "universal function" in your application

Comment: It's not even clear your system of equations has a unique solution for `M1` if you only specify `TR` and `gamma`. It is nontrivial to solve equations for arbitrary missing values if they are not linear. You might have luck in this example, but it is definitely not a simple task to program something that will generally compute your missing values, especially without the use of a symbolic computation. This is more of a mathematical problem than a programming one actually. You will probably have to treat every unknown differently.

Comment: So the only equation which needs to be solved dependant on the given input values is the `TR=...`, right? as @knedlsepp wrote, there are two solutions possible for `M1`, if you cannot add additional constraints (such as `M1 > 0`)

Comment: @knedlsepp, terrible sorry of that, the "M1" will always be positive; in fact, all other values will be specified to be in positive.

Comment: @Jethro: Just wanted to address your "*sure there is a simple solution to account for such scenario*". Sadly there is no simple solution for a general set of equations. You will probably have to deal with every case individually.

Comment: @knedlsepp, I guess I can only hope they amend this in the future. Can the symbolic toolbox achieve the same thing, though?

Comment: You can use the symbolic toolbox to generate the different solutions and generate ordinary matlab functions out  of that. I can provide you with a hacky solution, which assumes that you have the symbolic toolbox available at least for generating these functions; you won't need the toolbox for actually executing the generated functions then.

Comment: I just tried that (generating matlab functions) for the case: `TR` and `gamma` are given, `M1` is calculated. When I re-read your question, would you like to supply **arbitary** combinations of two variables, e.g. `M2` and `rhoR` and matlab should derive the remaining 6 values? This is maybe possible but complicated ...

Comment: @m.s. Yeah, my intention is to do that, if the user supplied let's say `rhoR` and `M2`, the matlab code will run automatically and gives me the remaining undefined variables. But it would be very complicated, as I understand, so I guess the case will be limiting to one equation only, for `M2`, example: user will define `gamma` and `M2`, and then matlab would find `M1` for me. This value, along with the input `gamma` will used to find for other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we already wrote in the comments, what you try to do is very complicated and rather infeasible without the symbolic toolbox.

I have written a hacky solution which only accounts for the case:
2 out of the 3 variables `{TR, gamma, M1}` are given, the third one is then automatically calculated. These 3 variables can then be used to solve the remaining equations.

This solution assumes that you have at least **once** access to the symbolic toolbox, but you won't need it when you use generated code.
We first generate MATLAB functions based on the symbolic expression for each of the following cases:

- `{TR, gamma}` given, `M1` missing
- `{TR, M1}` given, `gamma` missing
- `{gamma, M1}` given, `TR` missing

This results in 6 m-files to be written, `sol_TR.m`, `cond_TR.m`, etc.

```
syms gamma M1 TR;
assume(gamma, 'real');
assume(gamma > 0);

assume(M1, 'real');
assume(M1 > 0);

assume(TR, 'real');
assume(TR > 0);

eq = TR ==(((gamma - 1)*M1^2 + 2)*(2*gamma*M1^2 - gamma + 1))/(M1^2*(gamma + 1)^2);

vars = {gamma, M1, TR};
num_vars = size(vars,2);

for i=1:num_vars
    current_var = vars{i};
    [sol, ~, cond] = solve(eq,current_var, 'ReturnConditions', true);
    matlabFunction(sol, 'File', sprintf('sol_%s',char(current_var)),'Vars', vars, 'Optimize', false);
    matlabFunction(cond, 'File', sprintf('cond_%s',char(current_var)),'Vars', vars, 'Optimize', false);
end
```

These functions can then be used to calculate the missing variable:

```
function [input_vector] = calc_third(varname_1, var_value_1, varname_2, var_value_2)

     varnames = {'gamma', 'M1', 'TR'};
     num_vars = size(varnames,2);
     var_index = 1:num_vars;
     var_name_map = containers.Map(varnames,var_index);

     input_vector = zeros(1,num_vars);
     input_vector(var_index == var_name_map(varname_1)) = var_value_1;
     input_vector(var_index == var_name_map(varname_2)) = var_value_2;

     var_index(var_index == var_name_map(varname_1)) = [];
     var_index(var_index == var_name_map(varname_2)) = [];

     sol_func = sprintf('sol_%s(input_vector(1),input_vector(2),input_vector(3))', varnames{var_index});
     cond_func = sprintf('cond_%s(input_vector(1),input_vector(2),input_vector(3))', varnames{var_index});
     result = dot(eval(sol_func), eval(cond_func));

     input_vector(var_index)= result;
end
```

Example run:

```
>> calc_third('gamma', 0.5, 'TR', 100) 

ans =

     0.5000    0.0669  100.0000
```

You could of course build upon that solution and create a symbolic system of equations which incorporates all your 8 variables. You would then have to generate [28](http://www.hackmath.net/en/calculator/combinations-and-permutations?n=8&k=2&order=0&repeat=0) functions and select the approriate ones based on the given input variables.

---

However, I would not recommend that route. Try to get the symbolic toolbox where you need it, this should help you avoid a lot of headache.
You could use it then like this:

```
function [] = calc_third(varname_1, var_value_1, varname_2, var_value_2)

    gamma = sym('gamma');
    M1 = sym('M1');
    TR = sym('TR');

    eq = TR ==(((gamma - 1)*M1^2 + 2)*(2*gamma*M1^2 - gamma + 1))/(M1^2*(gamma + 1)^2);

    subs_eq = (subs(eq,[sym(varname_1), sym(varname_2)],[var_value_1,var_value_2]));

    missing_var = symvar(subs_eq)

    solve(subs_eq,missing_var)

end
```

Sample run:

```
>> calc_third('gamma', 0.5, 'TR', 100)

missing_var =

M1

ans =

(2*2^(1/2))/(3*88609^(1/2) + 893)^(1/2)
```

Comment: I should really push for an upgrade in my university. How will the approach be different with symbolic toolbox? More specifically, after I have make the variable `TR`, `M1` and `gamma` to be symbolic, how will I let matlab knows to solve for the remaining variables, after the users have input their variables.

Comment: @Jethro: I have updated my answer how MATLAB will substitute the known values and solve for the missing one.

Comment: Thank you! Is it by default for the Matlab symbolic toolbox to represent the answer in equation, rather than in the value?

Comment: the symbolic toolbox does not use numeric solutions as long as possible. you can convert the result to floating point by using `eval(solve(...))`.

Comment: I have managed to get a hold of a matlab with symbolic toolbox, but it gives such error:
`Warning: List of equation is empty.`
`ans = [empty sym]`

Comment: @Jethro: When running which code? You might open a new question for this.

Comment: For the case of multiple equation like above, where users can specify variable for other equations as well, ifelse will be sufficient, right? Or, is there any other approach?